# Can't change height and width of SVG in Firefox when layered on Canvas

Tags: javascript, firefox, svg, layer

Goal: An SVG layered on top of a Canvas, both of them changing their size when a PDF is rendered to the canvas.

Problem: The canvas resizes correctly and the PDF displays, but the SVG always has width of zero and height of zero, when examined in the inspector.

Note: This all worked when I was rendering a JPG directly into the element containing the SVG, but when I switched to rendering a PDF as an image I had to use a Canvas.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <canvas id="pdfcanvas"></canvas>
    <svg id="overlay"></svg>
    <input type='file' multiple='false', onchange='loadPDF(this)'></input>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#pdfcanvas {
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}

#overlay {
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
}
```

The javascript correctly opens the PDF and renders it in the canvas, but no matter what I try when I look at the SVG in the element inspector it has width and height of zero.  I've tried setting it's width and height to 100%.  I've tried explicitly setting its dimensions the same time that I set the canvas dimensions, i.e.:
    var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('pdfcanvas');
canvas.height = viewport.height;
canvas.width = viewport.width;

var overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
overlay.height = viewport.height;
overlay.width = viewport.width;
```

I've tried putting the svg before the canvas, nesting it inside the canvas...no effect.

Comment: It's an HTML element, what happens when you use the normal `overlay.setAttribute("width",canvas.width+"px");` and equivalent height?

Comment: Ok, I tried that and it revealed more clues.  The html in the inspector now shows the correct dimensions, but the box model still shows 0x0.  So I made the overlay red (it had been transparent) and sure enough it's showing up...but none of my D3 graphics appear in it.  I'll have to go back now and see if the other version was resizing it.

Comment: for future reference it's also a good idea to mention (ideally through code) which libraries you're using. In this case, showing the html document from `<!doctype html>` to `</html>` would probably help because it'd reveal that you're using d3.js and presumably a pdf.js or the like, too.